# How to nest multiple json objects together in a single response

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to send a response from a sinatra server with multiple json object.

I have an array of hashes similar to these:

```
{:a=>5, :school=>"some school"} && {:id=>5, :name=>"michael"}
```

I would like to append a key to each one say 'school' and 'student' then send that back to the browser in one request like:

```
[schools:[{werererererwre},{werwrwerwewe}],
 student:[{student1}, {student2}]
```

that's probably not fully formatted json but you understand what I'm trying to do, so then on the frontend I can just go

```
data.schools
```

to get an array of the schools

Comment: paste a sample hash of the school and students info, it'll help us understand what you actually want

Comment: To save yourself headaches use objects instead of primitives and add a `to_h` and `to_json` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
data:{
   schools:{ 
       school:{[ ], []}
       student: {[], [] }   
   }
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: wait what? how do i append my objects in there?

Comment: you can follow the above format to store the data as json object. To get only school data .try => data.schools.school, it will return only school information

Comment: The issue is not the structure, I need to know how to append my array into that structure? is it something like ['data']['schools'] << schools?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here's the spill.

```
hash = {}

hash[:schools] = {schools hash object}
hash[:students] = {student hash}

hash.to_json
```

and BOOMSHAKALAKA, DONE!